# How can I ask for a location into a waterfall dialog?

Tags: c#, botframework, bing-maps, .net-core-2.1

I am programming a chatbot in .Net Core 2.1.
I want to ask the user for a location such as [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Location). But in my conversation, I use a waterfall dialog (from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs) and there is no Location Prompt in this library. So my question is, is it possible to use [this code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) into a waterfall dialog? If yes, does anyone have an idea about how to do it?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** No. That repo uses BotBuilder V3 and Waterfall Dialogs are in V4. However, there is a [V4 version available in a different repo](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.Location).

**Long answer:** The [BotBuilder-Location Repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Location) uses [BotBuilder V3](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-v3), which is pretty outdated. If you want to build a bot with that prompt in V3, the [BotBuilderLocation Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Location/tree/master/CSharp/BotBuilderLocation.Sample) and the [BotBuilder V3 Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp) should help.

That being said, I highly highly recommend against building a new bot in V3--there are fewer features and much more limited support and documentation.

**Prompting for Location in V4**

First, I recommend taking a look at [BotBuilder Community Extensions](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet). These are unofficial extensions to the Bot Framework. There' actually already a [Location Dialog](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.Location) available, which is the same as you linked, but ported to V4. It has samples and very good instructions to get it running within a Waterfall Dialog.

Additionally, [Virtual Assistant](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/docs/readme.md#overview) does something very similar in its [Point of Interest Dialog](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-solutions/blob/master/skills/src/csharp/pointofinterestskill/pointofinterestskill/Dialogs/PointOfInterestDialogBase.cs), that you can look at for an additional example.

If you're wanting a much simpler prompt for location, I recommend reading the [Prompt Users for Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-primitive-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) docs. I'm not sure what your experience level is, but this is a good place to start for a beginner.

Comment: Thank you !! I am trying to use the BotBuilder Community lib. I am looking at this [code](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.Location/LocationDialog.cs) but I have some difficulties. On this sample, they use `BingGeoSpatialService(apiKey)`, but I have an error since it's an `internal class `and I can't use it in an external assembly. Do you have any ideas on how/where I can log my Api Key?
I saw I can use reflection but it's not recommended...

Comment: You pass in your API Key when you instantiate a new `LocationDialog`. [See here](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.Location#usage)